# Will the future C++ standard support "Declaring type template parameters with auto"

Tags: c++

Current C++ standard already supports "Declaring non-type template arguments with auto"?

Question: will the future C++ standard support "Declaring type template parameters with auto"

Once supports, the STL container can be changed to:

```
template<auto T>
class vector {

}
...
int main () {
    vector<auto> v = {1 ,2 3};
    vector<auto> v = {{1},{2},{3}}; // 2d vector.
}
```

This change would really save lots of typing. However, it would make front end much more complicated. I am not sure if it's possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: "*will the future C++ standard support "Declaring type template parameters with auto"*" What does that mean? What's the difference between `template<typename T>` and `template<auto T>`? Also, `template<auto T>` *already* has a meaning. Which makes this notion doubly confusing.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, template<auto T> has meaning for non type template. I don't think it has meaning for type template, does it? Thanks.

Comment: @kk9527: There's no such thing as a "type template" or "non type template". There are type template *parameters* which are distinct from non-type template parameters. What distinguishes them is how they are *declared* in the template header, not how they are *used* in the template definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see `vector<auto> v = {1 ,2 3};` being added to C++.  The reason for this is because C++17 already has [Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).  That will let you write your code like

```
std::vector v = {1, 2, 3};
```

and `v` will get deduced to a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Or if the OP really wants to use `auto` in there somewhere, `auto v = std::vector{1, 2, 3};`.

Comment: a use case not completely pointless: `[](X<auto> x) { .... }` instead of `[] <class T> (X<T> x) { ... }`

Comment: another one: `std::array<std::string_view, auto> a = {"yolo", "qwerty"}`;

Comment: @bolov `std::array a = {"foo"sv, "bar"sv};`

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I found "vector<vector>> vv = {{1}};" is still not support. Is there chance std support it (2 layers) in the future?

Comment: @kk9527 The problem with nested structures like that is that `{{1}}` doesn't actually have a type.  The language would need some major madifications to get it to work.  What you can do though is use `auto matrix = std::vector{std::vector{1,2,3}, std::vector{3,4,5}};`.  CTAD doesn't work with aliases yet but that functionality will be added so the code can be shortened to `template <typename T> using vec = std::vector<T>; auto matrix = vec{vec{1,2,3}, vec{3,4,5}};`